# Petición https a nodejs con socket io y express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Estoy tratando de hacer una petición `https` a una **api** que esta corriendo en el puerto 3000 y me arroja un error al intentar conectarme desde el front:

```
GET https://72.29.91.218:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MAmkbFu net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Mi conexión es la siguiente:

```
this.socket = io('https://72.29.91.218:3000', {secure: true, reconnect: true});
```

Y mi api esta de la siguiente manera:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
// var server = require('http').Server(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./sockets.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./sockets.crt')
};
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Auth, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');

    next();
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('solicitudGasolina', function(data){
        socket.broadcast.emit('solicitud gasolina', data);
    });

    socket.on('autorizacionGasolina', function(data){
        socket.broadcast.emit('gasolina autorizada', data);
    });

    socket.on('gasolinaValidada', function(data){
        socket.broadcast.emit('gasolina validada', data);
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

¿Alguna solución para esto o que estoy haciendo mal?
Cabe mencionar que el `crt` es auto firmado.

Comment: segun el error, dice que la autorizacion con tu certificado es invalido.

Comment: entonces necesito comprar un certificado?

Comment: no necesariamente, revisa tu codigo ya que talvez sea el problema en la generacion de la autofirma

Comment: y que error te arroja?

Comment: en la consola del navegador me arroja esto:
GET https://72.29.91.218:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MAmkbFu net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: intenta acceder por dominio

Comment: otra opcion que te doy accede a tu url y acepta el socket

Comment: genere por tercera vez el crt y ya funciono, tenias razon, estaba generando el crt incorrectamente